# How to save a downloaded file in particular path using selenium web driver with existing driver instance

Tags: selenium

How can I save the downloaded file in particular path with same existing the driver instance using selenium web driver?
I have used the Firefox profile method, but in that we need to create a new instance of driver every time to when we required to download. so I just want use the existing instance of driver.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use FirefoxProfile Settings to specify the path for the files to download.

```
String profilePath = "ProfileName";
FirefoxProfile profile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile(profilePath); 
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","/Users/test/Downloads/WebDriver/");           profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");

DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, profile);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

Comment: Sorry its not working for me, its not handling the Dialog box, its not saved the file.

Comment: Did you give profile name that you've in your machine? And also did you change the folder path ? What is the version of firefox & WebDriver?

Comment: yes i given, but not work, i get same pop dialog window, version of Firefox is 24.0 and webDriver is 2.40.

Comment: Can you paste your code here (otherwise edit the question and post)? that how you're initialising driver instance ?

Comment: FirefoxProfile fp= new FirefoxProfile();
  fp.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
  fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
  fp.setPreference("browser.download.dir","E:\\Download");           
  fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip");

  DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox(); 
  dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
   Driver.driver(fp);
   

   try {
    if(idMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("name")){
     Driver.driver.findElement(By.name(locator)).click();

Comment: Try to create a new firefox profile and give that profile name while creating instance of profile.==>  FirefoxProfile profile = new ProfilesIni().getProfile(profileName); ===> here is the firefox profile creation help link ==> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Comment: Hi santhosh, i am creating new firefox profile also but it is not work. please tell any other solution.